# Wordpress wp_nav_menu not showing nav

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, footer

trying to add a footer menu to my footer in WordPress, The menu is saved inside the database and I'm copying the same code from the header which is working perfectly. I can't see the error:

code is:

```
     <?php 
          if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer_nav' ) ) {
            wp_nav_menu( array('container' => '<ul>', 'menu' => 'Footer Menu', 'items_wrap'  => '<li>%1$s</li>' )); 

          }
            ?>
```

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the `theme_location` for `footer_nav`,

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=>'footer_nav', 
                    'container' => '<ul>', 
                    'menu' => 'Footer Menu', 
                    'items_wrap'  => '<li>%1$s</li>' ));
```

Comment: still not working, output I'm getting is: <li>menu-footer-menu</li>

Comment: I replaced the items_wrap with <ul> and removed container and it worked.